# How to allow context menu to be multiple selection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox, contextmenu

For a label, I have a list of items to show on context menu and can select many items. 
Can it be a checkbox for each item on context menu?

Below is my current xaml codes:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Count}">
    <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Label.ContextMenu>
</Label>
```

**additional question**: about remove the empty gap infront of the checkbox,  I have used @Rohit reply already but it still has a line behind the checkbox item. Can it be delete?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can have checkBox. Simply replace `TextBlock` with `CheckBox`.

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
  <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

---

**Update for comment**

> how to remove an empty gap infront of the checkbox?

First please refrain from asking follow up questions in comments since it's not visible to larger audience here.

Now for your question - That's default template of ContextMenu which is getting applied. To avoid that you to **override `Template` of ContextMenu**. Refer to the template from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case interested (modify it as per your needs)

However, there is quick and dirty way to achieve that by **`specifying negative left margin`**:

```
<CheckBox Margin="-35,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

Comment: Thank you it's work. I have another question. how to remove an empty gap infront of the checkbox?

Comment: Could you please chec the question again? I have a new problem. Thank you.

Comment: Like I mentioned you have to override `ControlTemplate` to remove that. Please raise separate question for that since it's completely different from the original posted question here. Thanks..!!